# Create a user document onCreate and onUpdate that is in sync with the auth.user Firebase v9

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to securely create a `user` document onCreate that is in sync with the `auth.user` database in Firebase v9.
I think it wouldn't be secure to let a registered user create a user document. So I wrote a cloud function which triggers on auth.user onCreate `functions.auth.user().onCreate()`.
But as I want my users to input a display name or other information on sign up, I also want them to be stored to both db entries as well. But I have a problem keeping them in sync as I can't await the `onCreate()` cloud function trigger and so don't know when I can update the `user` document with all the data that wasn't submitted by `user().onCreate()` like the `displayName` and so on.
I tried and searched everywhere. I can't believe this is not a standard feature and still a requested topic. This seems so basic.

#### Error

`error FirebaseError: No document to update:`

#### Sign Up function

```js
interface SignUpFormValues {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    confirm: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }

const handleSignUp = async (values: SignUpFormValues) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = values;
    const displayName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

    try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);
      // Create User
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        values.email,
        values.password
      );
      // -> Signed in

      // Update Profile
      const user = userCredential.user;
      await updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: displayName,
      });
      // IMPORTANT: Force refresh regardless of token expiration
      auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);

      // Check if user document already exists
      // Get the from cloud functions onCreate created user document -> currently having an error because the doc is no created yet
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log("docSnap.exists()", docSnap.exists()); // currently false
      console.log("docSnap.data()", docSnap.data());

      // Update user document
      const newUserData = {
        displayName: displayName,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      };
      await updateDoc(docRef, newUserData);

      // Send Email verification
      await authSendEmailVerification(user);

      // Logout
      await logout();

      navigate("/sign-up/email-verification", { state: values });
    } catch (error: any) {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error", error);
      console.log("error", errorCode);
      if (errorCode === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        const errorMessage =
          "Failed to create an account. E-Mail address is already registered.";
        setError(errorMessage);
        console.log("error", errorMessage);
      } else {
        setError("Failed to create account.");
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

#### Cloud function which triggers the user onCreate

```js
// On auth user create
export const authUserWriteListener = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate(async (user, context) => {
    console.log("user:", user);
    const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    await userRef.set({
      email: user.email,
      createdAt: context.timestamp,
      firstTimeLogin: true,
    });

    return db.doc("stats/users").update({
      totalDocsCount: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think it wouldn't be secure to let a registered user create a user document.

Why not? [Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) can be used so the user can update their own data only. So you can run `updateProfile` and `updateDoc` right after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

> I have a problem keeping them in sync as I can't await the `onCreate()` cloud function trigger

If you still want to use Cloud functions, then you can use [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and create user account, update all the required information in it and then sign user in with client SDK. So on client side:

```
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions();
const createNewUser = httpsCallable(functions, 'createNewUser');

createNewUser({ email, password, displaName, ...otherData })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function. (user account is created)
    // Sign user in with client SDK 
  });
```

Also checkout:

- [Firestore security rules allow user access to their data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49249528/13130697)
- [Firebase authentication is not putting out displayName when using cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58741087/13130697)
- [Firebase Cloud Function - null user.displayName onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60446655/13130697)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I probably found a third way but it seems to work only sometimes. But I can't find the mistake. I'm now awaiting for the user document to be created with `onSnapshot` like this: ```return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(userDocRef, {
    next: (doc) => {
      unsubscribe();
      console.log("doc.data()", doc.data());
      resolve(doc.data());
    },
    error: (error) => {
      unsubscribe();
      console.log("error", error);
      reject(error);
    },
  });
})```

Comment: It's useful but not solving all my issues. Ok I will write a new question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @BenjaminK what's the issue though? You just shared some code without any errors. Also why do you need to listen to document updates (what are you trying to do after document is updated)?

Comment: I updated the question with an error code `error FirebaseError: No document to update:` which was before only describes as a response behavior. I want to listen to document updates as my main issue is that the document I'm trying to update does not yet exists as it's created within the cloud function when  user `onCreate` triggers.

Comment: @BenjaminK are you just trying to update user name in Firestore? You can do that by using `set({...data}, {merge: true})` so even if document is missing it'll create one. Same from Cloud function but it might end up in race conditions...

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm trying to do as you can see in my code above. `await updateDoc(docRef, newUserData);`. But this docRef does yet not exist as I'm not able to await the cloud function. And I didn't want to grad a user permission to create a document only to update, that's why I wanted to solve it with cloud functions. This brings me to the firestore `onSnapshot` method I wanted to use to wait in my `handleSignUp ` function for the backend creation of the document before updating it.

Comment: @BenjaminK it might be better to use cloud functions only. Like creating user and adding their doc with relevant details in a single cloud function. What's not ideal in the approach?

Comment: I found this a helpful article. But in v9 it seems that the `onSnapshot` method is not working for me. [link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07) . One of the alternatives would be to do it in a single cloud function, but this would probably bring me to new unknown problems which is why I want to use it as a last chance.